# Reflecting everything from 127.0.0.1 to 192.168.. for presentation

Tags: php, wordpress, proxy, localhost

I have a Wordpress website on 127.0.0.1, but I need to show it via 192.168.. Is there any PHP script that working like a **local tunnel**? How to solve that? Thanks!

Comment: That should already work without any changes or tools If that is the network ip of your server that should simply work if there are no firewall restrictions. Try it in browser

Comment: No, not for everything.. Wordpress doesnt work like that..

Comment: Wordpress or no wordpress, web works like that. The only reason apart from network issues that it wont work is if the url is hardcoded in the wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

To find out your computers IP address, try this

`ipconfig` (For Windows, on command line Start->Run->cmd-> enter ipconfig ->Hit Enter)

`ifconfig` (For *nix console)

The fire up your browser and navigate to that IP address. Voila :)

EDIT

When using wordpress, make sure your `siteurl` value in your database is NOT set to localhost or 127.0.0.1. That would make you try to call wordpress from the PC you are visiting from. You should put in the IP address you have found out using the steps I mentioned above.

You can find the `siteurl` setting in your wordpress database, table name is `wp_options`